# How to make C function visible to Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to embed Racket in C++, how do I accomplish something like this

```
Scheme_Object* c_function(int argc, Scheme_Object** objects) {
  printf("a c function with %d args", argc);
  return scheme_null;
}

scheme_eval_string("(c_function)", env);  // c_function undefined
```

I try `scheme_make_prim_w_arity`, but it seems I can use `scheme_apply` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`scheme_eval_string`, like other forms of `eval` in Racket, operate on particular *namespaces* and won't be able to find functions or other bindings not available in those namespaces. You should:

- Read [this section of the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html#%28part._namespaces%29) about `eval` and namespaces.
- Not use `eval` -- it's almost always the wrong tool.